# What is equivalent API of org.jfxtras.util.BrowserUtil in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx-2

I convert code from javafx 1.3 to javafx 2.1. This API is in javafx 1.3, But i don't know equivalent API in javafx 2.1.

Comment: org.jfxtras.* stuff is not JavaFX API but 3rd party library. You need to convert this lib sources as well.

Comment: Thank you Sergey Grinev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HostServices.showDocument()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument%28java.lang.String%29) will open a url in a browser window (similar to what the jfxtras BrowserUtil did).